# Connect online quickbook to my php website

Tags: quickbooks-online

I am in need of generating invoices on my online quickbook account automatically through my php website.
i searched a lot over intuit and other sources but dont know where to start or what to do.
please help me..
Thanks

Comment: Is this a SaaS app (e.g. you are charging many companies monthly to allow them to connect their QuickBooks to your app) or a one-off/custom/internal integration for a single company?

Comment: i think its a one-off as i am not charging to get invoice from quickbook for users of my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-SaaS QuickBooks integration with QuickBooks Online, you want to use qbXML.

To do this, you first need to register with Intuit. It's easiest to register in DESKTOP mode. There are instructions to do this on our [QuickBooks PHP wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition#connecting_with_the_desktop_model_of_communication). Register as a PRODUCTION application (you can only use DEV/PTC if you get a special account from Intuit, which you won't be able to get).

Once you've registered, you'll have a connection ticket, an app id, and a app login.

Then, you can grab our [open source PHP QuickBooks DevKit](http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/) (use a recent nightly build) and open this example:

- docs/example_online_edition.php

From there, you plug in your app id, app login, and connection ticket, and you'll be able to send XML formatted requests to QuickBooks.

You'll want to use Intuits [QuickBooks OSR](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) for XML reference. Make sure to check "OE", uncheck "US", change the qbXML version to 6.0 (QuickBooks Online only supports 6.0), use the "Select Message" drop-down to choose the request type, and the "XML Ops" tab to see the available XML fields.

Your resulting code will look something like:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../QuickBooks.php';

// Register in DESKTOP mode to get these. Docs: 
//  http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Online_via_qbXML#Connecting_with_the_.27Desktop.27_model_of_communication
$application_id = '134476443';
$application_login = 'qboe.www.consolibyte.com';
$connection_ticket = 'TGT-68-1sRm2nXMVfm$n8hb2MZfVQ';

// Create our new gateway instance 
$Gateway = new QuickBooks_Gateway_OnlineEdition(
    $application_id,
    $application_login,
    $connection_ticket);

$xml = '<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <VendorAddRq>
                <VendorAdd>
                    <Name>ConsoliBYTE</Name>
                    <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>    
                    <LastName>Palmer</LastName> 
                    <VendorAddress>
                        <Addr1>123 Test Road</Addr1>    
                        <City>Mt Pleasant</City>    
                        <State>MI</State>   
                        <PostalCode>48858</PostalCode>  
                    </VendorAddress>
                    <Email>support@consolibyte.com</Email>  
                </VendorAdd>
            </VendorAddRq>
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>';

// Send the request
$resp = $Gateway->qbxml($xml);

print($resp);
```

Comment: ok i went through all the steps - registered on intuit,      made a new productive mode application too...added appid,aplogin.app ticket to the script. i added xml code to add customers on quickbook. i ran the script and i didnt get any error but there is no addition of customers on my online quickbook account. what should i do? why i dont see any errors though?

Comment: Post the XML response you get back from Intuit. And post your code.

Comment: i sent the code by an email to keith@ConsoliBYTE.com from muditdugar89@gmail.com   please check and help me. Thanks

Comment: plz ignore last msg....all working fine... Thanks a lot
btw is there any pdf describing the various functions and the parameter values in detail for say creating a customer shown in xml format in this link https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html  ?

Comment: If you download the QuickBooks SDK, there's a 600 page PDF with lots and lots of detail about each request type. Generally though, the request types mirror the QuickBooks GUI almost exactly, so if you poke around the GUI it's pretty easy to figure out the requests.

Comment: hi,again
ok i am all set with online version...now i want my php website to create invoices automatically to my desktop quickbook software. is this possible? please provide me instructions like you did for online thing....thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You should ask a new question (or, better yet, search the existing questions) since it's a different topic than this question is.

Comment: hi...ok plz answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352871/connect-desktop-quickbook-to-my-php-website
Thanks