# connect to QuickBooks online via PHP

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

Short Version:

How do I connect to my company's QuickBooks Online subscription via a PHP script to retrieve some relatively simple information like a list of Customers or a list of Invoices?

Long Version:

Okay, so I've spent all day trying to figure out how to connect to QuickBooks Online via PHP, and I'm still stuck.  Either I'm an idiot, or this whole thing is more complicated than trying to make my wife happy.  It looks like the QuickBooks API changes every couple years, any many of the posts from the recent past are now incorrect.

Basically, I am simply trying to write a php script which connects to my company's QuickBooks Online account.  I need to do very simple things like retrieve a list of customers, retrieve a list of invoices, and so on.  While researching, I found this post from June 2013:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17226869/3195596

The post says to use qbXML, download the QuickBooks PHP Dev Kit, and look at the example in "docs/example_online_edition.php":

So, I downloaded the QuickBooks PHP Dev Kit (from here: http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/) and went into "docs/example_online_edition.php".  This php file now says "DO NOT USE THIS FILE ANYMORE!"  It also says that "All QuickBooks Online implementations should now be using the v3 REST APIs.".

Therefore, my understanding at this point is this:  Before I even connect to my company's QuickBooks Online account, I first have to create a developer account at developer.intuit.com (aka Intuit Partner Platform aka IPP).

So, I registered with IPP, and now I'm just stuck with nowhere to go.  My IPP account is not connected to my company's QuickBooks Online account - am I supposed to connect these somehow?

Can anyone explain to me in somewhat plain English how I would connect to my company's QuickBooks Online account via PHP?

Comment: The best solution is to contact quickbook and ask them what's the correct steps to connect to their REST web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125191/connect-quickbooks-ipp-to-quickbooks-online).

And the nice guys at Intuit responded fairly quickly.  Their answer, as I understand it, is that I need to build an application under my QuickBooks IPP account, then use OAuth to tie it to my QuickBooks Online account.

Answer (score 0):

I am written extensively on the basics of connecting to QuickBooks. The articles are Rails based but a user of any programming environment can benefit from them.

[Get started integrating Rails 4 and QuickBooks Online (QBO)](http://minimul.com/get-started-integrating-rails-4-and-quickbooks-online-with-the-quickeebooks-gem-part-1.html)